# AppleScript Safari, open URL in CURRENT window

Tags: safari, applescript

Using AppleScript, Can I open a URL in the CURRENT Safari window (i.e. without opening a new window or tab)?

I want to create a history so that I can hit the backarrow through a few web pages but only have one window open.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure you can :)

```
tell application "Safari" to set the URL of the front document to "whateverURLYouWant"
```